# do/until loop continues after condition met

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am having an issue attempting to automate moving computer objects from one OU to another. I am attempted to move for one OU then repeating the pattern for multiple OUs. But after the condition of the until is met, the `do` loop continues.

```
$groupA = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer))" -SearchBase "OU=Group,OU=clients,OU=WSUS computers, DC=Domain,DC=com"
$GroupACount = $groupA.Count
$groupA_computers = $groupA | select name -ExpandProperty name
$groupB = "OU=GroupB,OU=clients,OU=WSUS computers, DC=domain,DC=com"

write "group A had $GroupACount Computers"

if ($GroupACount -gt 120) {
    write "Computers need to be moved from group A "
    Start-Sleep 5
    do {
        foreach ($computer in $groupA) {
            Get-ADComputer $computer |
                Move-ADObject -TargetPath $view |
                write "Computer $computer has moved to $groupB"
        }
    } until ($GroupACount -eq "2")
} else {
    write "$groupA is below threshold"
}
```

Comment: You need to update the value for `$GroupACount` *inside* the do..until loop

Comment: The `foreach` inside the `do...until` will run to completion, moving all of the computers in GroupA into the target path. And it will do so repeatedly, until GroupACount - which is not being updated - drops to 2. I don't think this is what you really want to do. Check your logic.

Comment: Since you know how many you have, and how many you want, that's where a `for` loop with a counter as an index will work.

Comment: the issue is I don't know how many I have. We have roughly 12 containers I will need to run through and dump into one container if it is over the threshold. Also I was able to update my count to reflect computers leaving the OU but  the count hit zero and continued to loop repeating the computers and the zero.

Comment: @CaigeKelly Change `$GroupACount -eq "2"` to `$GroupACount -le 2`

Answer (score 0):

I would add the following line in your `foreach ($computer in $groupA)` loop so it decrements your `$GroupACount` integer, as currently your `$GroupACount` value never changes so it will never meet the `Until` condition:

`$GroupACount--`

like so:

```
$groupA = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(objectcategory=computer))" -SearchBase "OU=Group,OU=clients,OU=WSUS computers, DC=Domain,DC=com"
$GroupACount = $groupA.Count
$groupA_computers = $groupA | select name -ExpandProperty name
$groupB = "OU=GroupB,OU=clients,OU=WSUS computers, DC=domain,DC=com"

write "group A had $GroupACount Computers"

if ($GroupACount -gt 120) {
    write "Computers need to be moved from group A "
    Start-Sleep 5
    do {
        foreach ($computer in $groupA) {
            Get-ADComputer $computer |
                Move-ADObject -TargetPath $view |
                write "Computer $computer has moved to $groupB"
                $GroupACount--
        }
    } until ($GroupACount -eq "2")
} else {
    write "$groupA is below threshold"
}
```